# Java JFrame key listener stops working randomly

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, 2d

I'm trying to create a 2d game in Eclipse using a JFrame and keylistener. My code looks like the following:

Main.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    DrawerManager game = new DrawerManager();
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Game");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    frame.add(game);
    frame.pack();
    frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    frame.setVisible(true);
    frame.addKeyListener(game);
}
```

DrawerManager.java

```
public class DrawerManager extends JPanel implements KeyListener {

    public Scene scene = new GameScene( sceneContext );

    int frame = 0;

    public long last = 0;
    public int ups = 30; //UPDATES PER SECOND

    public DrawerManager() {

    }

    @Override
    public void processKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
        super.processKeyEvent(event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        ...
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {}

    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        scene.keyPressed(e);
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        scene.keyReleased(e);
    }

 }
```

GameScene.java

```
 public class GameScene extends Scene{

    GameContext context;
    Player player;


    public GameScene(SceneContext sceneContext) {
        ...
    }

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent event) {
        Logic here
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent event) {
        Logic here
    }

 }
```

When just launching the game it works fine but after some time it randomly stops receiving any events. My initial thought was that it had something to do with holding down multiple keys, but that doesn't seem to be the case. From my tests I can see that holding down space for a couple of seconds for some reason makes it work again. Keep in mind that the issue is very random, sometimes it happens right away and sometimes it doesn't happen for a very long time.

The issue seems very odd, as the game is extremely simple right now I cannot see anything that would interfere with the event listener. I also tried exporting the code to a jar file with no luck...

I'm running the code in Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.1a) on Mac.

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: What does _logic here_ do?  Perhaps it eventually takes too much time, causing the UI to not respond.  [This](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) might help.

Comment: @AndrewS Thanks for the suggestion, however I don't think it's the case. I added some debugging to the code, and it appears that the events take maximum 1 ms to execute each, which should be totally fine.

Comment: What about `paintComponent()`?  Maybe it eventually takes a lot of time.

Comment: @AndrewS I think I forgot to mention, other game objects continue to move, aswell as a FPS counter etc. So the general game logic continues working. Logging indicates that the events just are never called.

Comment: maybe the jpanel loses focus - if you have jpanel on top of jpanel then the right element has to have the focus. you have to post a complete code - otherwise no answer.

Comment: @gpasch Tested that too, but it isn't the case. I see now that the keyReleased event is indeed called but the keyPressed event just stops being called for some reason. I also tried using a KeyboardFocusManager which acted exactly the same way...